# How to get data in form of QString from QVariant in Qt5?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qvariant

I have a QVariant with userType QVariantList and the exact format looks like this when i qDebug the qvariant

```
QVariant(QVariantList, (QVariant(QVariantMap, QMap(("name", QVariant(QString, "UK English Female"))))
```

I want QString, "UK English Female" from the variant how can i get that i have already tried `QVariant.toStringList()` but the stringlist is empty. 
Thanks.

Comment: Could you provide a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)? It is unclear what you are asking. It looks like you need to write a couple lines of code to build a string, but you don't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what is shown as a debug output, I presume it was produced in a similar manner:

```
QVariantMap map;

map.insert("name", QVariant("UK English Female"));
qDebug() << QVariant(QVariantList{QVariant(map)});
```

and as a result you have a string data, which is burried relatively deep in a sequence of containers.

So, how to get there?

As a whole you have a *QVariant* holding a *QVariantList* with a single *QVariant* value, which in turn is a *QMap*. The map has a key *name* of type *QVariant* holding a *QString*. Chaining the necessary conversions, we end up with:

```
qDebug() << myVar.value<QVariantList>().first().toMap().value("name").toString();
```

assuming the whole thing is held in `QVariant myVar;`.

Comment: Thanks a lot it solved my problem. Actually am getting that variant by calling a JS function in QWebview. :)